# Lost Custom CSS File

Tags: css, restore

I had my site branded nicely last week (ok, nice is a strong word).

Today, I updated the master page to bring jQuery into the fold and noted that My.css was checked out.  I was going to undo the checkout but then thought it would be safer to check in to see what had changed.  I did so and ended up with an earlier version of the file.  I tried to restore to a previous version but those were worse.

Now it appears that I've lost my work :-(  Is there some magic version control recycle bin that I can open up?

I can restore the database from backup but wasn't ready test that skill yet.  Can I just restore the config db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS file wouldn't be in the config db anyway, all site content (when unghosted, ie: saved through the browser or SharePoint Designer) is stored in the content database.

I would check out the file, and restore each version until you get what you think is the most recent version.

Do this through the UI, as SharePoint Designer is laggy when referencing a newly restored version of an old file, and you'll open up what you think is the newly restored version but it'll be the same as the one before. Annoying as hell.

If you checked it in it should've created a minor version at the time you did, so try and restore that, via the UI, and open it to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Thanks!  That's good to know.
After the panic yesterday afternoon, I found that it was all still in there.  The lagging issue probably was interfering because I was restoring versions as fast as my mouse could click them.

Comment: Fell down that very trap myself, with the lagging in SPD when restoring versions.